# Can a replica to an RDS MySQL instance be setup outside RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have a running RDS Mysql 5.7 instance that I would like to replicate to a MySQL 8 instance running on a Linux server (not on RDS).

Is this possible? I cannot find an option to do this from the dashboard.

Answer (score -1):

you can do that with database migration tools.

see the last section of this [page](https://linuxdiaryblog.blogspot.com/2019/08/aws-migration-from-on-premise-to-cloud.html)

Comment: This page is about moving MySQL from on-premise to AWS. Not what my question. I want to create a live replica from RDS to on-premise, as in the master instance is RDS and the slave is on-premise.

Comment: you mean this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-DAiakBfKI

Comment: I think EastsideDev means the other way around. Source is RDS, destination is a stand-alone server.

Comment: No, Attunity is not a real time replication service and it's a third party tool

Comment: @TeroKilkanen yes and it needs to be realtime not a tool that saves the data to a local disk and then you upload. This is realtime replication/